# {"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006} gitlab

Tags: gitlab, webhooks

I want to integrate a bot via a weebhook between Gitlab and discord, so I've configured the bot first, copied his url and put it into the gitlab weebhook configuration input and set it for sending push updates to the Discord server.

With a real push test, I have (with the body)

```
Request headers:

Content-Type: application/json
X-Gitlab-Event: Push Hook
```

and as response

```
Response headers:

Date: Tue, 26 May 2020 18:46:48 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 58
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d374998c2f84e3e20b75bbdec88fb63d91590518808; expires=Thu, 25-Jun-20 18:46:48 GMT; path=/; domain=.discordapp.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax, __cfruid=418f7199379a53d23012d37b15f2ac5a3aac36b6-1590518808; path=/; domain=.discordapp.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Ratelimit-Bucket: 3cd1f278bd0ecaf11e0d2391374c011d
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 5
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 4
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1590518811
X-Ratelimit-Reset-After: 2
X-Envoy-Upstream-Service-Time: 12
Via: 1.1 google
Cf-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Cf-Request-Id: 02f3e816a1000004823d920200000001
Expect-Ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
Cf-Ray: 5999a9376a790482-CDG
```

but got the error:

```
Response body:

{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}
```

or also

```
Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 400 {"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: For anyone wondering, this error is simply returned if you send an empty string to a Discord webhook.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "Integrations" feature for "Discord notifications" instead of regular webhook.

See [documentation here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/discord_notifications.html)